# Completion Block becomes nil in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, completionhandler

I checked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41745328/2666902), but the issue occurs in my case is totally different.

I am using `typealias` to avoid rewriting similar completion block declaration.

```
typealias FetchFilesCompletionBlock = ( _ files: OPFiles?, _ error: Error?) -> Void
```

In the function definition, I am using the optional type of `FetchFilesCompletionBlock`. Even though, the function is called with a completion block, in function body onCompletion becomes nil.

```
func fetchFile(_ param: [String: String]? = nil, onCompletion: FetchFilesCompletionBlock?) {
  // I found onCompletion is nil here.
  // function body
}
```

That `fetchFile(_: onCompletion:)` is called as follows:

```
let onCompletion =  {(files, error) in
  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {[weak self]() in
    self?.onCompletion(files, error: error)
  })
} as? FetchFilesCompletionBlock
// Here also I found that onCompletion is nil
dataManager.fetchFile(param, onCompletion: onCompletion)
```

If I remove the `as? FetchFilesCompletionBlock` from the above snippet, I got a compile-time error `Cannot convert value of type '(OPFiles?, NSError?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'FetchFilesCompletionBlock?'`.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you forgot to specify the type of `onCompletion`. With the declaration of `onCompletion` you need to also specify its type that it is `FetchFilesCompletionBlock`.

```
let onCompletion: FetchFilesCompletionBlock = {(file, error) in
    //Your code
}
dataManager.fetchFile(param, onCompletion: onCompletion)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nirav , it works well. Could you please tell the reason behind?

Comment: @MilanKamilya Welcome mate :), I have already written that you haven't specify the type of `onCompletion` with its declaration that's the issue.

Comment: Could you please tell what is the difference between  `as? FetchFilesCompletionBlock` & `let onCompletion: FetchFilesCompletionBlock`

Comment: @MilanKamilya Type casting with block will never going to work, so `as? FetchFilesCompletionBlock` will always fail

Answer (score 1):

issue is that in the block definition you used Error as your error's class , but in the the block you created you used NSError instead, while they r compliant they r not "implicitly" casted, and by doing what Nirav proposed you "explicitly" casted the difference (NSError to Error)

Comment: That's correct. Thanks @HusseinDimessi for deep inspection.

Comment: `let onCompletion =  {(files: OPFiles?, error: Error?) in
 }`  -  also solve the issue for the same reason.

Comment: just delete the s in the end of the Errors? here ;)
but yeah that will solve it for the same reason